# graphLookup StartWith Object instead of Array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

today a i read about the $graphLookup feature and i was totaly impressed about this (for me) new feature.
Currently i solve these type of problems with eval and now i gonna transfer these functions to $graphLookup.

One of these functions is "getAllSubFolders()". And now i got in some troubles, because my
connectFromField is a object, rather than being an array (as in the mongoDB documentation examples).

To unterstand this better:

Folder documents are structured like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58286a66d43ee415567ab4c8"),
    "Children" : {
        "File_58286ce0d43ee415567ab4e5" : "58286ce0d43ee415567ab4e5",
        "Folder_5829d284d43ee41fa74f7e50" : "5829d284d43ee41fa74f7e50",
    },
    "UserID": "1"
   ...
}
```

Now as i mentioned, i need a aggregation pipeline (with $graphLookup?) which will give me all subfolders back.
Any ideas how to solve this?

To be more specific: My current problem is startWith. I need something like:

```
db.folders.aggregate( [
{ $match : { "UserID" : "1"  } },
   {
      $graphLookup: {
         from: "folders",
         startWith: "getObjectValues($Children)", //returns an array with the object values
         connectFromField: "getObjectValues($Children)", // not sure about this
         connectToField: "_id",
         as: "sub_folders"
      }
   }
]);
```

PS: Nice but not needed would be if we search only for Children which has Folder_ in the key. I don't know if there's a possibility to filter it.

```
Ok, so our origin document looks like this:
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("581bae37d43ee401131d8293"), 
    "UserID" : "37", 
    "Children" : {
        "File_581bb4abd43ee401131d82a0" : "581bb4abd43ee401131d82a0", 
        "Folder_581bc233d43ee401131d82b8" : "581bc233d43ee401131d82b8", 
    ...
    }
}
Now we need an query that return this document:
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("581bc233d43ee401131d82b8"), 
    "Children" : {
    "Folder_5826034c0c0a1c005d64f921" : "5826034c0c0a1c005d64f921"
    }, 
}
but also the child folder with the id 5826034c0c0a1c005d64f921.
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5826034c0c0a1c005d64f921"), 
    "Children" : {
        "Folder_593032743f54cc0078025802" : "593032743f54cc0078025802"
    }
}
... recursive, down to the last element (until the object children contains no more folders)
```

Overall the result should like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("581bc233d43ee401131d82b8"),
    "Children" : {
    "Folder_5826034c0c0a1c005d64f921" : "5826034c0c0a1c005d64f921"
    }, 
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5826034c0c0a1c005d64f921"),
    "Children" : {
        "Folder_593032743f54cc0078025802" : "593032743f54cc0078025802"
    }
},
```

Comment: Do you really want `$graphLookup`? Perhaps you would be better off explaining what you want to do. All the pipeline stage really does is traverse a tree and shows the parent hierarchy within a result array of the ancestor document. If having all the parents visible from the ancestor is your goal, then this is for you. If you are trying to build a "tree view", then maybe or maybe not. It depends on your concept of how you want to process it.

Comment: My main problem is that eval is on state "deprecated" and i need a way to get from a folder all subfolders. Its a filesystem. My final goal is to get then all files from all subfolders($in query) and $sum the file-sizes

Comment: I think instead you should be showing documents and the result you want rather than making presumptions about which method to use. Certainly not `eval()`. Show more document detail and less about asking for usage of a specific method.

Comment: Thanks for your help Neil. I updated the question

Comment: Okay so an expected result is something, but what are the documents that should have produced that result? Perhaps you should have a brief read of the [MCVE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and understand that in order to "solve" something we need to be able to "repoduce and verify".

Comment: I'm sorry that my explanation wasn't good enough to understand. I edited the question now with the starting document.

Comment: The core problem I see here is your documents are not stored in a way that works with the concepts available. At the most basic level you have "strings" that you want to match to `ObjectId` values. Nothing is going to do that for you. So having variable key names here is not good and you will need to change that. But having mixed types is even worse. I think you should at least consider the techniques suggested in the core manual article [Model Tree Structures](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/). There is at a glance quite a lot to do here.